# Arpspoof on Debian - Linux isn't working

Tags: wireshark, arp-spoofing, raspberry-pi

I'm using the following code:

```
>sudo bash 
>echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
>arpspoof -i wlan0 -t [Victim IP] [Gateway IP] #on terminal num.1
>arpspoof -i wlan0 -t [Gateway IP] [Victim IP] #on terminal num.2
```

And checking the traffic with WireShark, for some reason no information between the Victim and the Gateway is transferred to me, I'm using netcat chat and I want to intercept the chat between the "Victim" and his "friend" (another computer), the chat is not encrypted.
I also get a "duplicate use of [Victim IP] detected!" error on WireShark from the Gateway that keeps repeating.

Any idea why its not working?

Using 3 RaspberryPi3 with Raspbian Jessie, on wifi.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your interface in promiscous mode, you can do it as following

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 promisc
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Maybe it's not necessary to turn down and up the interface

Comment: actually promisc doesnt enable me to receive  all traffic on the router since im not in monitor mode. but even with that its not working.